# pdo mysql timestamp filter being ignored

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

I'm trying to select records from a table created in the last 24 hours using the function below. I don't understand why it is returning all records rather than just last 24 hours worth (created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)).

Any advice appreciated.

```
function getActive()
{
global $dbh;

$statement  =   $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))");

$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Jobs');

$statement->execute();      
$result     =   $statement->fetchAll();


return ($result)?$result:array();
}
```

Comment: what's the type of `created`? Unless it's an int and storing an actual unix timestamp (seconds since Jan 1/1970), your comparison will fail because it'd be an apples/oranges situation.

Comment: What data type is `created`? It should be `DATETIME` as native data types are often better than forcing external conventions in your database.

Comment: the data type is 'timestamp'

Comment: Marc you are absolutely right I didn't even notice '> UNIX_TIMESTAMP'  fixed the fixed the type a in the query and all is well again.

Answer (score 0):

first check your created column data type if it's correct then try this

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE created < date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -24 HOUR)
```

Comment: Subtracting a positive value and adding a negative value should be the same thing.